# Android action bar color and menu

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have some problems with the Action bar of my App. I would like to change the background color of my action bar, so I used this code. THe problem is that I always get a NullPointerException (bar is always null). What can I do?

```
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

I also wanted to add a drop down menu in the top right corner of the app (in the action bar). So I used this xml code and this event:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/spinner"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner" />
</menu>
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); // set the adapter to provide layout of rows and content
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener); // set the listener, to perform actions based on item selection
```

But I always get some errors in the yourapp:actionViewClass (I always get a wrong prefix error whatever I use as myapp) and in R.menu.menu_layout (R.menu does not exist). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What type of Activity are you using? Do you have an ActionBar or a Toolbar?

If you are using SupportActionBar, you can try:

```
getSupportActionBar();
```

For the menu problem, do you have the menu layout in a `res/menu` folder?